# Angular ng-grid/ui-grid implementing view logics inside views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am trying to create grid with advanced features(filter, re-sizable, scrolling, fixed header, row formatting, cell formatting) using angular js. I have read the following grids documentation.

- [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/)
- [ng-table](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/)
- [smart-table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/)

**And, ng-grid has many features and perfect for our requirements. but I want the following 2 options also. is it possible to achieve from ng-grid?**

- **Formatting**

We have number of columns in my grid (approx 40). Most of the column data need to be formatted in cell. for eg: Adding link, change date format, Reducing length of the content with tooltip..etc., Here, I can not do this stuff inside views. But this one is handled perfectly in ng-table.

If I can not do this in view, then my javascript (using callbacks) code is going to be increased. I don't want this way because angular perfectly do dynamic views.

Also, I want Header formatting, filter formatting, row formatting should be done inside views.

- **Responsive using Bootstrap**

Our application should work in all devices. but ng-grid not working as responsive if I view my application in tablet devices.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on the following grid [angular grid](http://www.angulargrid.com/) - has the features you mention. Similar to ui-grid in it's basic interface, but approaches things differently, including how the grid is customized. You can add css styling at the column and cell level, as well as providing your own custom cell renderers for complete control.

Answer (score 0):

Asik,

The project **Angular-UI** renamed the **ng-Grid** to **UI-Grid** and the website changed to http://ui-grid.info.

Now it's pure AngularJS, without jQuery, use Bootstrap 3 LESS and it's full features that fill your requirements.

Take a look in the page of Tutorials to check the power of features.